# Getting back empty arrays/ variables when uploading .txt file to Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, variables, file-upload, text-files

I am trying to load a .txt file with data to Matlab to use for some calculations. However, when I run the code the variables/arrays come back empty or blank. 
Below I have the code I am using.

```
%% importing the data
% Open file in the memory
fileID = fopen('rainfall.txt');
% Read the txt file with formats: Integer, Integer, Float

% Treat multiple delimiters, which is "space" in here, as one. Put the data
% in a variable called chunk.
chunk = textscan(fileID,'%d %d %f','Delimiter',' ',...
'MultipleDelimsAsOne',1);
% Close file from the memory.
fclose(fileID);
% date
dt = chunk{:,1};
% hour
hr = chunk{:,2};
% precip
r = chunk{:,3};
% remove extra variables from Matlab workspace
clear fileID ans
```

In the Workspace tab in Matlab it shows `chunk` to be an empty `1x3 cell`. This results in dt, hr, and r not having any values either and are listed as having a value of `[]`. So my best guess is that something is going wrong with loading in the data to Matlab.

Also, here is small portion of the data I am working with. This is exactly how it is written in the .txt file as well.

```
STATION           DATE           HPCP     
----------------- -------------- -------- 
      COOP:132367 20040116 22:00 0.01     
      COOP:132367 20040116 23:00 0.01     
      COOP:132367 20040117 00:00 0.04     
      COOP:132367 20040117 01:00 0.02     
      COOP:132367 20040117 02:00 0.00
```

In the actual file I have a lot more data than what I have listed here, but this should give an idea of what the data looks like and how it's formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [textscan help page](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html):

> textscan attempts to match the data in the file to the conversion specifier in formatSpec. The textscan function reapplies formatSpec throughout the entire file and stops when it cannot match formatSpec to the data.

So the first problem is the title lines. You should discard them. For example, by manually reading 2 lines (using `fgetl`). 
Next, you should make sure that the format matches the data. You tried reading 2 integers and a float but you also have the station name.
I think the following should be ok:

```
fileID = fopen('rainfall.txt');
l = fgetl(fileID);
l = fgetl(fileID);

chunk = textscan(fileID,'%s:%d %d %d %f','Delimiter',' ',...
'MultipleDelimsAsOne',1);
```

Comment: So this didn't completely fix the problem. Now it's only reading the very first station and stopping. This did help me see where the problem is though, so hopefully I can fix it. Thanks!

Comment: It’s probably the formatting. I used ‘%s:%d’ because that’s what you wrote in the example. Maybe the other station are different? You can try using only ‘%s’

Comment: Yes! That was the issue! It also didn't like the date so in the end this is what my code looks like: `chunk = textscan(fileID,'%s %d %d:%d %f','Delimiter',' ',...
'MultipleDelimsAsOne',1);`  I'm new to Matlab and being forced to learn it in a graduate class, so I really appreciate the help!